# WOW64 woes (.lnk shortcuts)

Tags: windows, delphi, shortcut, shellexecute, wow64

I'm using Windows 7 (x64) and Delphi 2010.

I'm writing a component that will emulate the start menu. However, I've run into the following problems:

1. If I attempt to open a shortcut (.lnk file) with `ShellExecute`, this will fail whenever *%ProgramFiles%* is part of the target path of the shortcut (it will then look at the *C:\Program Files (x86)* folder instead of *C:\Program Files*);
2. `ShGetFileInfo` fails to extract the correct index of the icon in the system image list if *%ProgramFiles%* is part of the path to the icon file (same problem as above).

Is there any workaround to the above issues or do I have to wait for native 64-bit Delphi to become available for this to work?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should call [`Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365743%28VS.85%29.aspx) before and [`Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365745%28VS.85%29.aspx) aftyer.

Comment: Ok, this is very annoying. While Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection does not solve my initial problem, it solves the problem whenever %windir% is used as part of the path name. One would expect that this would adjust/redirect all environment variables!

Comment: I don't think that's going to work.  All that does is disable redirection so that accesses to c:\windows\system32 (as an example) from a Wow64 program don't get redirected under the covers to c:\windows\syswow64.  As far as I know this doesn't do anything to help you with environment variables.  You'll either have to compile as native 64-bit or handle environment variables yourself.

Comment: Ok, SetEnvironmentVariable('ProgramFiles', 'C:\Program Files') fixes the problem for ShGetFileInfo, but the problem still remains for ShellExecute.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, a small example that demonstrates the problem.

I invoke ShellExecute with the following parameters:

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', 'C:\Users\...\Internet Explorer (64-bit).lnk', nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

The target of *Internet Explorer (64-bit).lnk* is:

```
C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
```

However, the 32-bit version of *iexplore.exe* is opened nonetheless. In this case the path doesn't even use *%ProgramFiles%*, so somehow `ShellExecute` will translate *C:\Program Files* to *C:\Program Files (x86)* internally. I have no idea how to make it open the 64-bit version of *iexplore.exe* instead.

Another problem, after calling `Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection`, `ShellExecute` will no longer open folders.

Comment: This is *not* an answer to the question. Please add additional details in the question instead.

Comment: Sorry, I'm newly registered, when I added openid to my account I lost the identity that I used when posting the question...

Comment: More info on this issue can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386715/launching-shell-links-lnks-from-wow64

Answer (score 1):

The following environment variables will always point to the right direction on a 64-bit machine, and will be undefined on a 32-bit machine:

from a 32-bit shell on a 32-bit architecture:

```
C:\>echo %processor_architecture%
x86
C:\>echo %programfiles(x86)%
%programfiles(x86)%
C:\>echo %programw6432%
%programw6432%
C:\>echo %programfiles%
C:\Program Files
```

from a 32-bit shell on a 64-bit architecture:

```
C:\>echo %processor_architecture%
x86
C:\>echo %programfiles(x86)%
C:\Program Files (x86)
C:\>echo %programw6432%
C:\Program Files
C:\>echo %programfiles%
C:\Program Files (x86)
```

from a 64-bit shell:

```
C:\>echo %processor_architecture%
AMD64
C:\>echo %programfiles(x86)%
C:\Program Files (x86)
C:\>echo %programw6432%
C:\Program Files
C:\>echo %programfiles%
C:\Program Files
```

Try substituting them before running the application.